# Are GTD techniques applicable to PM?

Tags: planning, tools

Is [Getting Things Done](http://www.davidco.com/what_is_gtd.php) helpful in terms of understanding PM, and does it make any direct contributions?

I'm not asking whether GTD will make **you** better organized, or more effective generally.  I mean, has it led to practical tools for PM?

Comment: It's not a question, but a topic to discuss. This site is for project management questions and answers.

Comment: Thanks for the perspective, and for moderating.  I would comment that a number of recent posts that seem to me to fail the standard have stayed open.  I realize, of course, these decisions are subjective and always ready for contention on StackExchange.  Respectfully.

Comment: @Smandoli you will help us all if you flag those questions. We, the same as you, are interested to keep this site clean and focused. Thanks!

Comment: Actually for me the subject is interesting and while the question wasn't phrased very neatly I believe it would belong here after some rephrasing or approaching it from a bit different angle.

Comment: I am also in favor of keeping it open. It is very original, to say the least. I am also a bit worried that a single person can decide to close a question.

Comment: @Stephan - Feel free to edit it to improve it.  I also encourage you to leave comments on questions you vote to close explaining why you feel the question should be closed.  As moderators, our votes are instant and binding, so we try to use these tools with moderation and let the community intervene.  You have enough reputation to use close and reopen votes, so use them!  ;)

Comment: OK, I rephrased the question and I voted to reopen it.

Comment: Thanks everybody.  I liked the last re-write ... a lot ... so I went and re-wrote it again, more in my own style.  :-)  Hopefully it better reflects the focus of the forum.

Comment: Nice to know. I voted to reopen. Still 3 votes short!

Comment: Hi All! Nice work bringing this question back to life!  I went ahead and re-opened this question since it's been edited to be an actual, real, answerable question! This is exactly the type of behavior I expect to see out of the community. Let's continue using those close/reopen votes!

Comment: Where's my Lazarus badge?!

Comment: @Smandoli - You probably have to wait for the script to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a great fan of GTD, and I believe in **custom-fitting to take what benefits you.** Things I found from GTD that are great when applied to project management:

- Formally tracking "waiting-for" tasks  (eg. dependencies on work from other teams)
- Keeping everything documented electronically (at least, my GTD systems are always like this)
- Using a calender to track specific dates (with email notification) for things due on that date (I tend to use a giant spreadsheet and not keep too many dates)

Other than that, GTD doesn't really add much to project management. You'll get more out of PMI's framework, or a specific methodology like Agile.

Comment: Thanks!  Frankly, I'll take the answer overall as a "No", merely because the points you listed can be as easily grasped with no awareness of GTD.

Comment: Yeah. GTD's "waiting fors" is really, really useful.

Comment: agile approaches aren't methodologies

Answer (score 8):

One element of GTD that has been helpful for me in project management is the habit of asking "What is the next action?" when a particular issue, problem, or mini-project is discussed in a meeting.  All too often, meeting participants can leave the room without the "next action" being identified.  Thinking in terms of GTD for my personal productivity has led me to ask this question more often.